# Unity - Spawn Prefabs (Clone Object) got wrong position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn prefabs (clone object) **AGAIN** with random position after it's **SetActive(false)**.

**What I want :**

After **Swimmer Object** enter trigger with **Prefabs (clone object)**,

set **Prefabs (clone object)** to **SetActive(false)** and then it must spawn in random position.

**What I have done :**

Swimmer.cs <-- This is make clone abject **SetActive(false)** when trigger

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Trash") {
            other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }
}
```

Trash.cs

```
    public GameObject columnPrefab;                                 
    public int columnPoolSize = 5;                                 
    public float spawnRate = 3f;                                    
    public float columnMin = -1f;                                  
    public float columnMax = 3.5f;                                  

    private GameObject[] columns;                                   
    private int currentColumn = 0;                                  

    private Vector2 objectPoolPosition = new Vector2 (-15,-25);     
    private float spawnXPosition = 10f;

    private float timeSinceLastSpawned;  

void Start()
        {
            timeSinceLastSpawned = 0f;


            columns = new GameObject[columnPoolSize];

            for(int i = 0; i < columnPoolSize; i++)
            {
                columns [i] = (GameObject)Instantiate (columnPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }


        void Update()
        {
            timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;
                if (GameControl.instance.gameOver == false && timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate) {   
                    timeSinceLastSpawned = 0f;


                    float spawnYPosition = Random.Range (columnMin, columnMax);

                    // This part what I am using to set it active
                    columns [currentColumn].SetActive(true);
                    columns [currentColumn].transform.position = new Vector2 (spawnXPosition, spawnYPosition);

                    currentColumn++;

                    if (currentColumn >= columnPoolSize) {
                        currentColumn = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
```

**What I have got :**

Prefabs (Clone Object) succeed spawn but on wrong position (float on right)

You can take a look at this image [image: Click here.]

So, how to SetActive clone object and spawn it for random position? Thanks

Comment: What does the Inspector say that cloned object's position is, and what do you want it to be?  Also, where do you set `objectPoolPosition`?

Comment: I set the position here 
float spawnYPosition = Random.Range (columnMin, columnMax);
columns [currentColumn].transform.position = new Vector2 (spawnXPosition, spawnYPosition);

Comment: What I mean is I don't see the code where you're setting the `objectPoolPosition`.  Please update your question with it, and show what the inspector says is your position for your cloned object.

Comment: I have edited the Trash.cs, please see the code above

Comment: I learn from this tutorial https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/recycling-obstacles-object-pooling?playlist=17093

Comment: When you select the cloned object that's at the wrong position, what does the Unity inspector say its position is?

Comment: Nevermind... I see the problem.

Comment: It's X: 10 , Y : random

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189317/discussion-between-lamberto-fredrick-nababan-and-ben-rubin).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't actually a problem, and everything in your game is working like it should.

You have your Scene View scrolled out slightly further than your Game View.  You can see that if you look at the green seaweed on the left of your screen.  See how your Scene View shows more leaves?

The Scene View is purely for the Unity editor, and you can zoom and scroll around independently of where your camera is in your Game View.  If you want to move the camera within your Game View, you have to either change the camera parameters on the Main Camera object in your Hierarchy, or you can update `Camera.main` through code.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you can edit the Main Camera object in the Unity Hierarchy, or you can use C# code to update `Camera.main`.  I recommend looking up a quick tutorial on the Unity camera.